# What is the "right way" to signal specific instances of QML objects from C++?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

**Right up-front, I'll apologize:**  This is a monster question, but I wanted to provide what I hope is all of the pertinent details.

I've got a QML-based GUI that I was tasked with taking over and developing from proof-of-concept to release.  I believe the GUI is based on an example provided by QT (Automotive, maybe?).  The GUI is being compiled for web-assembly (emscripten) and features a "back-end data-client" which communicates with our hardware controller via a socket and communicates with the GUI via signals.  The GUI is accessed via web browser and communicates with the `Data_Client` via `QWebSocket`.

[image: Simple Block Diagram]

The GUI proof was initially created with a very "flat" hierarchy where every element is created and managed within a single `ApplicationWindow` object in a single "main" QML file.  A `Data_Client` object is instantiated there and all the other visual elements are children (at various levels) of the `ApplicationWindow`:

```
ApplicationWindow {
id: appWindow

//various properties and stuff

Item {
    id: clientHolder
    property Data_Client client
}

ColumnLayout {
    id: mainLayout
    anchors.fill: parent
    layoutDirection: Qt.LeftToRight
//And so on...
```

The `Data_Client` C++ currently emits various signals in response to various things that happen in the controller application.  In the main .QML the signals are handled as follows:

```
Connections {
        target: client 
    onNew_status_port_data:
        {
            textStatusPort.text = qdata;
        }
        onNew_status_data_act_on:
        {
            imageStatusData.source = "../imagine-assets/ledGoodRim.png";
        }
    //and so on...
```

What I'm trying to do is create a `ChannelStatusPanel` object that holds the various status fields and handles the updates to those fields (text, images, etc.) when it receives information from the `Data_Client` backend.  There are multiple instances of this `ChannelStatusPanel` contained in a `MainStatusPanel` which is made visible or not from the main `ApplicationWindow`:

[image: GUI Basic Layout]

Having said all of that (Phew!), I come finally to my question(s).  What is the correct way to signal a specific instance of the `ChannelStatusPanel` object from the `Data_Client` with the various data items needed to drive changes to the visual elements of the `ChannelStatusPanel`?

I thought I was being clever by defining a `ChannelStatusObject` to hold the values:

```
Item {
    id: channelStatusObject

    property int channel
    property int enabled    //Using the EnabledState enum 
    property string mode
    property int bitrate
    property int dataActivity   //Using the LedState enum
//and more...
    property int packetCount
}
```

In the `ChannelStatusPanel.qml`, I then created a `ChannelStatusObject` property and a slot to handle the property change:

```
property ChannelStatusObject statusObject

    onStatusObjectChanged: { 
//..do the stuff
```

From the `Data_Client` C++ I will get the information from the controller application and determine which "channel" I need to update.  As I see it, I need to be able to do the following things:

1. I need to determine which instance of `ChannelStatusPanel` I need to update.  How do I intelligently get a reference to the instance I want to signal?  Is that just accomplished through `QObject::findChild()`?  Is there a better, faster, or smarter way?
2. In the `Data_Client` C++, do I want to create an instance of `ChannelStatusObject`, set the various fields within it appropriately, and then set the `ChannelStatusPanel` instance's `ChannelStatusObject` property equal to the newly created `ChannelStatusObject`?  Alternatively, is there a mechanism to get a reference to the Panel's `ChannelStatusObject` and set each of its properties (fields) to what I want?  In C++, something like this:

```
QQmlComponent component(&engine, "ChannelStatusObject.qml");
QObject *statObj= component.create();

QQmlProperty::write(statObj, "channel", 1)
QQmlProperty::write(statObj, "bitrate", 5000);
QQmlProperty::write(statObj, "enabled", 0);

//Then something like using the pointer from #1, above, to set the Panel property
//QObject *channelPanel;
QQmlProperty::write(channelPanel, "statusObject", statObj)
```

Is there some other, more accepted or conventional paradigm for doing this?  Is this too convoluted?

Comment: I don't think you want a reference to a specific object. That's not usually how signals/slots work. You just emit a signal, without caring if anyone is listening. And it's up to the receiver to decide if that message is relevant to them. I would maybe just emit a signal with an index parameter or something identifiable. ALL of the ChannelPanels would receive the signal, but only the one that matches the index would do anything with it.

Comment: JarMan: either your statement is incorrect, or I'm misunderstanding it. The Qt connect() call explicitly ties together one sender object and one receiver object.

Comment: At least within the context of how this program CURRENTLY operates, the visual elements are all instantiated by whatever the behind-the-scenes mechanisms are for the `QGuiApplication` and `QQmlApplicationEngine`.  There are `emit` calls from the backend and `onSignalName` slots in the QML.  Nothing calls `connect()` on them explicitly; I assume the connections are done by whatever the intermediate (whatever the right term is) processes are that normally connect QML and C++ implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go about this using Qt's model-view-controller (delegate) paradigm. That is, your C++ code should expose some list-like `Q_PROPERTY` of channel status objects, which in turn expose their own data as properties. This can be done using a `QQmlListProperty`, as demonstrated [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html#properties-with-object-list-types).

However, if the list itself is controlled from C++ code -- that is, the QML code does not need to directly edit the *model*, but only control which ones are shown in the *view* and possibly modify existing elements -- then it can be something simpler like a `QList` of `QObject`-derived pointers. As long as you do emit a signal when changing the list, this should be fine:

```cpp
class ChannelStatus : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Q_PROPERTY(int channel READ channel CONSTANT)
    Q_PROPERTY(int enabled READ enabled WRITE setEnabled NOTIFY enabledChanged)
    // etc.
};

class Data_Client : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Q_PROPERTY(QList<ChannelStatus*> statusList READ statusList NOTIFY statusListChanged)
    // ...
};
```

The ChannelStatus class itself must be registered with the QML type system, so that it can be imported in QML documents. Additionally, the list property type will need to be registered as a metatype, either in the main function or as a static variable. Otherwise, only lists of actual `QObject` pointers are recognised and you would have to provide yours as such.

```
qmlRegisterUncreatableType<ChannelStatus>("LibraryName", 1, 0, 
    "ChannelStatus", "Property access only.");
qRegisterMetaType<QList<ChannelStatus*>>();
```

You then use this property of the client on the QML side as the `model` property of a suitable QML component, such as a `ListView` or a `Repeater` inside a container like `RowLayout`. For example:

```js
import LibraryName 1.0
ListView {
    model: client.statusList
    delegate: Column {
        Label { text: modelData.channel }
        Image { source: modelData.enabled ? "foo" : "bar" }
        // ...
    }
}
```

As you can see, the model data is implicitly attached to the delegate components. Any `NOTIFY`able properties will have their values automatically updated.

Comment: I believe this is going to end up being the answer, but I'm muddling through trying to prove it.  I will circle back and confirm this ASAP.  Thanks!

Comment: I still think this will be the correct way to go about this, but I currently don't see how to access the `ChannelStatus` data within the delegate Column section.  I guess I mean that `modelData` from your example isn't accessible, so how would I get `channel` or `enabled`?

Comment: Based on the link you provided, it looks like you CAN'T use QList and must instead use QQmlListProperty, instead.  I'm trying that now and will update.

Comment: @RichHoffman Yes it does suggest using that class, but it's not always necessary to do so. There are some subtle differences: with the method I described, you can only read the properties as `modelData.propertyName`, while the QmlList also makes them available directly as `propertyName`, along with the option to allow adding/removing items from QML.

Comment: I do see I forgot to mention one thing. If you want to expose the property as `QList<ChannelStatus*>`, which might be a useful format to manage them in C++, then it must be registered with `qRegisterMetaType`. Otherwise, only actual `QList<QObject*>` are recognised by default. I'll make an edit to reflect this.

Comment: It's so close now...  I have exposed the properties of `ChannelStatusObject` and there are the proper number of delegates visible with the correct data at creation time, but I'm not able to update the View and visible delegates.  When I emit the signal following an update to the values in the QList, I can break in the appropriate `Connections{}` block and see that the QList data is all updated, but nothing visibly changes.  Is there something else I need to signal?  I guess I thought the view:delegate:model paradigm would handle the update without some explicit "redraw" call...

Comment: Interestingly, if I clear the list and then re-create and append new `ChannelStatusObject *`, then call `emit statusChanged`, the View is properly updated with the "new" data.  This seems horrendously heavy-handed and I'm sure I'm just missing some critical last piece of the puzzle that allows me to edit the data within the specific `ChannelStatusObject *`, emit the signal, and see the update...  Is it that the POINTER ITSELF isn't changing within the list and just it's Q_PROPERTY values are, therefore not triggering a "change" of the model data?

Comment: @RichHoffman Indeed the QML bindings should update automatically whenever you use properties with NOTIFY. Did you also register the status object class with [`qmlRegisterUncreatableType<ChannelStatusObject>(...)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterUncreatableType) and import that module in QML?

Answer (score 1):

Below is how I've setup my application.

Front-end is in QML. Back-end is in Qt C++. H/W Controller application is in C.

In Qt C++ back-end, I have QObject derived database and databasePoint classes.
database object holds a QMap of databasePoint objects.
Each databasePoint object has a unique point name, which is used as an identifier.

database object is created in main.cpp and exposed to QML as a context property.
database class has a method to return a pointer to databasePoint object.
In QML, this method is used to create databasePoint objects.
When this method is called, a databasePoint object is created and added to QMap if it doesn't already exist.

**databasePoint class has read-write value properties.

These properties are used for communication between UI, back-end and controller.**
In a timer, latest value is polled from controller periodically, whenever there's a change, the value property is updated.
When the value property is updated from UI, the value is written to controller.

```
class database : public QObject
{
public slots:
    databasePoint* getDbpointObject(QString pointName);
private:
    QMap<QString, databasePoint*> dbPointMap;
};

class databasePoint : public QObject
{
    Q_PROPERTY(QVariant value READ value WRITE setValue NOTIFY valueChanged)
public:
    QVariant value(void);
    void setValue(QVariant value);
    QVariant my_value;
signals:
    void valueChanged();
};
```

DatabasePointComponent.qml:

```js
Item {
    required property string pointName
    property var pointObj: database.getDbpointObject(pointName)
}
```

MyScreen.qml:

```js
DatabasePointComponent{
    id: dbTEMP
    pointName: "TEMP"
}
TextInput {
    text: dbTEMP.pointObj.value
    onAccepted: dbTEMP.pointObj.value = text
}
```